Queueing a Series of State Updates
I have been read the "Queueing a Series of State Updates" in react docs.
link: https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#what-happens-if-you-update-state-after-replacing-it
I am facing with a exercise and i read solution but i don't understand why it run like this
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function RequestTracker() {
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(0);
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(0);

  
  async function handleClick() {
    setPending(p => p + 1);
    await delay(3000);
    setPending(p => p - 1);
    setCompleted(c => c + 1);
  }


  return (
    <>
      <h3>
        Pending: {pending}
      </h3>
      <h3>
        Completed: {completed}
      </h3>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        Buy     
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}


My question: I don't understand why when I click in button multiple times it just waits for 3 seconds for the first time and then it decreases pending to 0 and doesn't wait any 3 seconds. I think it waits 3 seconds for each decrease pending?

It's very unclear what you're asking. Specifically "it just wait 3-second [..] and doesn't wait any 3-second" makes no sense.

Thank you for your feedback. I have already edited my question

So what you mean is if you click on it multiple times quickly it is not waiting 3 seconds after every update? Because every click is scheduling the delay as soon as it is clicked right, so the wait starts from the very moment you click it. The waits are not scheduled sequentially.

I think when I click multiple times, each click will be handled separately. Because of this, it will await delay(3000) after each click. I don't understand the scheduling when i click multiple times
